# what is the difference between LMS and MPC?

Tags: control-systems, lms

I do understand that MPC is a control method and requires known model in the feedback path.
LMS, on the other hand, is more like an adaptive filtering, which estimates the tap coefficients yielding the minimum mean squared error. Plus, LMS does not require known model.

Besides the differences I mentioned above, what is the difference between LMS and MPC, and when would one use LMS (or MPC) over the other?

Comment: They are completely different, LMS basically has system identification built into it while MPC is optimizing based on known system dynamics. MPC will always perform better if the dynamics are known.

Comment: can I ask you why MPC would always work better? and from what perspective does this work better? as far as I know, LMS-based adaptive filtering will induce MMSE at the output. How is it possible for MPC work "better" in this context?

Comment: LMS assumes a LTI system model and gaussian input(or basically the input needs to cover all frequency bands) there is a specific term I forgot in systems theory. LMS will never converge exactly ly. If you have a deterministic model which is correct it will always work better.